# What exactly does $\langle a,b \rangle$ mean? Where a and b are elements of a group G?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Does it mean either a or b will generate the whole of $\langle a,b \rangle$ or does it mean that some of the elements will be generated by a, some by b, and some by $a^rb^q$? The book I'm reading doesn't really make it very clear.

Comment: Curiously, this question is *not* a duplicate, as can be seen by the answers. In the other post, the question is about a subgroup. However, the question here makes does not mention the word "subgroup" so requires a different method of answering (so although the resulting subgroups will be the same, due to the lack of information we are forced to form it differently).

Answer (score 3):

$H:=\langle a,b\rangle$ is formed by finite sequences of $a$ and $b$ i.e. $H = \lbrace e, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa\ldots \rbrace$

(if $H$ is infinite you might also have to add $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ to the mix)

If $H$ is abelian, you can simply say that $H = \lbrace a^rb^s\ : r,s\in\mathbb{Z}\rbrace$.

Comment: Ah so $a^rb^s$ and $b^ra^s$, as well as powers of a and b, thanks, that completely answers the question for me (r and s aren't consistent across the two)

Comment: @Nethesis Not only that, for instance $aba$ or is also in $H$.

Comment: Or any other arrangement of a and bs, now that I think about it

Comment: @Nethesis exactly. You got it now :)

Answer (score 2):

$\langle a,b\rangle$ denotes the group genereated by $a$ and $b$ and contains any "word" made with the alphabet $a, a^{-1}, b$ and $b^{-1}$: a typical element can be written as a product $$a^{{e_1}}b^{{f_1}}a^{{e_2}}b^{{f_2}} \cdots a^{{e_k}}b^{{f_k}},$$where all the $e's$ and $f's$ are integers. So $b^{15}a^2b^{-14}$ would be an example, as well as $abab^2ab^{-1}$, etc. etc.

Comment: I've edited your post to include inverses, as alphabets are not usually assumed to contain inverses.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks!